# How can I integrate views with controller state transparently?

Tags: php, mvc, web-framework

In a MVC application, integration between controller and views are often a matter of:

```
class HelloController {
  public function sayHello(Request $request) {
     return new Response($this->templating->render('view', [
       'name' => $request->get('name')
     ]);
  }
}
```

However, there are many frameworks out there which often perform "transparent" integrations of the view with the controller logic. For example, they allow for direct access to the CSRF token by simply writing `{{ csrftoken() }}` or similar in the view; this happens in an entirely transparent manner.

However, since I'm not using any framework, I'm forced to do something like this for most of the controllers:

```
$this->templating->render('view', [
  'name' => $request->get('name'),
  'csrf_token' => $this->getCsrfToken()
])
```

How can I perform such a transparent integration of controller state like most modern frameworks do?

Answer (score 1):

One way your `{{ csrftoken() }}` example can be implemented is by parsing the braces, [reflecting](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) over the underlying class to find the correct method to call, and replacing the braces and enclosing text with the return value of the method call.

**Further Reading**
[The anatomy of a simple templating engine](http://jsforallof.us/2014/12/01/the-anatomy-of-a-simple-templating-engine/)

Comment: I think what the OP means is how frameworks like CakePHP do to automatically load the view and output it without having to interact with it from the controller.

Comment: I think Robert already hit the nail on the head. The framework could be reflecting the controller's methods automatically. If the frameworks implements convention over configuration, the methods are mapped via configuration (annotations, attributes, etc)